# How to switch currency in WordPress based on geo location of the visitor?

Tags: wordpress

I built a website in WordPress and I need to show pricing for the services provided. However my requirement is that I should show the price in LKR for Sri Lankan visitors and in USD for anyone outside Sri Lanka.

Bearing in mind that this is not an e-commerce site.

How can I achieve this?

There are many plugins available for WooCommerce but not for my problem.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have prices in products in WooCommerce, there are free and paid plugins to do that, such as the plugin called: URCY - Multi Currency for WooCommerce

If it is plain text you can use the Geotargeting plugin to keep the same pages but with the text changed (in this case your price), another way is to use a plugin like Geo Redirects where you make duplicate web pages with different prices for each geolocation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I shall try this and see